# Drawing point and path graphic shapes in print layout of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts, drawing

At QGIS 3.4.4, I would like to freehand draw points and paths (i.e. zigzag lines) graphic shapes on my print layout.  However, I only see the option to draw rectangles, ellipses, and triangles, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

How do I add points and paths?

Please note that I am **not** talking about digitizing these onto my map; rather, these will be simple graphics, drawn by hand over non-map portions of the layout, such as the legend, etc.

Comment: "Add Node Item" for the lines?
For the points there is no specific command; you can always add small ellipses though.  Just make one and make it look the way you want, then copy/paste it as many times as you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Add a new arrow to layout` which is a graphic path and select `None` for `End marker`:

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Or you can also use `Add node item` and select polyline to add polyline directly:

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

For adding points, I agree with [@jberrio](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93912/jberrio) in his comment, there is no specific tool to do that. But for my understanding it might not be so important because you can create circle from ellipse and click <kbd>Shift</kbd> while drawing an ellipse and it will be perfect circle, and since the points can mostly be circles you can do it like that to be visible.

If you want the point marker to be squares then use `Add rectangle` with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make it perfect rectangle.

Comment: To complete this answer for point symbols you can use the add picture and insert an SVG symbol (it's not as convenient as having a point with SVG symbology but the visual effect is the same)

Comment: Another option for points: create a rectangle shape, and set its symbol to use a "centroid fill" with your desired point marker

Comment: Thanks to all!  The ellipse shift trick is very handy!

Comment: @StuSmith Glad it worked.

Comment: Ooops, I previously intended to accept your answer, but mistakenly clicked an upvote.  But now you have both.  Cheers!